# Access value of Django widget attribute

Tags: javascript, django

I have Django Form Field:

```
dob = forms.DateField(
    required=True,
    widget=NumberInput(
        attrs={
            "type": "text",
            "class": "datepicker",
            "autocomplete": "off",
            "placeholder": "DD/MM/YYYY",
        }
    ),
)
```

Now I need to access the "placeholder" value.
I use datepicker to change the format:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'mm-dd-yyyy',# **here I need to replace it with Django widget attribute.**
});
```

How can I get the value of the placeholder so I can do something like that:

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
format: {{django.placeholder | safe}},    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access placeholder value of the **dob** field in template you can do:

```
{{ form.dob.widget.attrs.placeholder }}
```